# Why do we need to give default value inside getBoolean() in kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to put some data whose key: "isLoggedIn" and a value: true inside a shared preference file.
I do it this way...

```
sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
 fun savePreferences(){
 sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("isLoggedIn",true).apply()
}
```

and then if I want to retreive/store this key-value pair inside a variable it allows me only when I give the second parameter which is a value or defualt value like this.

```
val isLoggedIn=sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLoggedIn",false)
```

The question is why do I have to  call the data by its name i.e., "isLoggedIn" and a default value in the getBoolean method instead of just calling it by the name like this code below.. ?

```
val isLoggedIn=sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLoggedIn")
```

Comment: The default is returned in case the key has no match inside the preferences. This is pretty standard for APIs which retrieve data stored somewhere to handle the case where that piece of data has never been stored before or deleted

Comment: So, you mean that getBoolean() is used to retrieve the data but when there is no such key which we entered inside the getBoolean() method that is present inside the preferences then we use default value to give some value for us despite not being present in the preference file .. so basically we can use this method just as putBoolean() when we don't have a match so it returns a default value that we have given?. Forgive me cause I'm a beginner so, this is a lot to get into my head. @MatPag

Comment: Default values are fallbacks.
If you never called `putBoolean("key", value)` before using `getBoolean("key", default_value)` or in general if the key is not present you will get back `default_value` instead. Read the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences#getBoolean(java.lang.String,%20boolean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also the `contains` function which checks if the key exists in the prefs (i.e. whether you've written a value for it or not) which can be useful if *not set* needs to be handled as a separate case. Maybe you need to be able to tell the difference between *not set* and a saved value of `false`, or `-1` or whatever, or maybe there's no natural default value you want to use (in this part of your logic at least - maybe something else handles that)

You could write some extension functions if you like:

```
fun SharedPreferences.tryGetBoolean(key: String): Boolean? =
    if (contains(key)) getBoolean(key, false) else null
```

You'll need one for each type you want to handle - you still need to pass a default to the `get` functions, but it'll never be used.

`getString` and `getStringSet` can both take `null` as a default, and you shouldn't be able to store null as a value ([`putString()` docs:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#putString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) *Passing null for this argument is equivalent to calling remove(java.lang.String) with this key*) so if you *do* get `null` out of the `getString` call you can assume it's the default because the key didn't exist. But if you're going the extension function route, I'd probably still make a `tryGetString` one just to be consistent

Comment: Wow thanks, I learnt some new functions now. @cactustictacs

Answer (score 1):

There nothing ensure that there is an existing value named "isLoggedIn" in the shared preferences, so you need to provide that default value so incase there is no value named "isLoggedIn", there default value is going to be returned.

You can try it by yourself by getting a boolean of a value that it doesn't exist in your shared preferences and log the result, something like this:

```
val randomBoolean = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("randomBoolean",false)
Log.d("randomBoolean", "$randomBoolean")
```

The result of the log will be `false`, and if you give `true` as a default value, the result will be `true` because there is no value named `randomBoolean` in the shared preferences so the default value is going to be returned.

That's why we need to give a default value.